# awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Tags: shell, awk

I have huge xml file that I want to split based on the element with minimum records i.e. 100 per split file.

In this example xml there are only two records so awk should create 1 xml file for each stuRec because I hard coded minimum number of files to 1.

But I am getting error: "awk: illegal statement at source line 1"
And I don't know how to fix this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<studentData>
<stuRec>
 <as>
 <sourceSys>BBC</sourceSys>
 <acctDt>2023-04-04</acctDt>
 </as>
 <stats>
 <ss>
  <prov>AB</prov>
  <cono>1</cono>
 </ss>
 </stats> 
</stuRec>
<stuRec>
 <as>
 <sourceSys>RCD</sourceSys>
 <acctDt>2023-05-14</acctDt>
 </as>
 <stats>
 <ss>
  <prov>ON</prov>
  <cono>2</cono>
 </ss>
 </stats> 
</stuRec>
</studentData>

awk -v element="stuRec" ' BEGIN { n =1; i = 1} /<\// && $0 ~ "</" element ">" { n++; } {print $0 > "output/part_" i ".xml"; if (n % 1 = 0) { i++; } }' "student_records.xml"
```

Comment: With `GNU awk 5.2.1` I get a syntax error from `(n % 1 = 0)`; primary issue is that `=` is used for assignments while `==` is used for comparisons.  Try replacing `(n % 1 = 0)` with `(n % 1 == 0)`.

Comment: please update the question with the expected output

Comment: `if (n % 1 = 0)`? Even if you use the correct `==`, the remainder when you divide any integer by one is *always* zero.

Comment: Don't cram your whole script onto 1 line and then you'll find it much easier to debug an error message that tells you which line the problem is on. We'd also find it much easier to help you with it.

Comment: Where is the opening `<studentData>` tag? Please provide a valid well formed xml document.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/view/tools/xml_split/xml_split

Comment: @ufopilot I thought about that (instead of a script that uses `XML::Twig`, but `xml_split` changes the name of the root element so it requires extra post processing.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is the wrong tool to use when working with XML; you need something that actually understands the format, like the incredibly handy [`xmlstarlet`](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). An example script that first uses it to find the number of `stuRec` nodes in the document, and then loops through, making new XML files with a given number of them in each:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage:
# ./split.sh input.xml output-dir [step-size]

xmlfile=$1
outputdir=$2
# Default to 100 elements at a time
declare -i step=${3:-100}

# First, find the number of stuRec nodes
declare -i nodes
nodes=$(xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v 'count(/studentData/stuRec)' "$xmlfile")

#printf "There are %d stuRec nodes\n" $nodes

# Now step through $step at a time, creating a new XML document with just the
# records in that range:

declare -i fileno=1
mkdir -p "$outputdir"

for (( i = 1; i <= nodes; i += step)); do
    # Delete all the stuRec nodes outside of a given position range
    xmlstarlet edit -d "/studentData/stuRec[not(position() >= $i and position() < $i + $step)]" "$xmlfile" > "output/part_${fileno}.xml"
    fileno+=1
done
```

---

And since you said it's a large file, here's a perl script that uses the [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) module (Install with your OS's package manager or favorite CPAN client) to read the XML document once (And not have to hold the entire parsed document in memory; it's intended for efficient handling of really big XML files):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# Usage: split.pl [--step=N] input.xml output-dir
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say state/;
use XML::Twig;
use Getopt::Long;

my $step = 100;
GetOptions("step=i" => \$step)
    or die "Error in command line arguments\n";

die "Usage: $0 [--step=N] input.xml output-directory\n" unless @ARGV == 2;
my ($xmlfile, $outputdir) = @ARGV;

mkdir $outputdir;

my $xml = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        stuRec => sub { handle_records(0, @_) },
        # Used to catch the last block of records
        studentData => sub { handle_records(1, @_) }
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented'
    );
$xml->parsefile($xmlfile);

sub handle_records {
    state $fileno = 1;
    state $records = 0;
    my ($last, $twig, $elt) = @_;
    if ($last || ++$records == $step) {
        my $partname = "${outputdir}/part_${fileno}.xml";
        # say "Creating $partname";
        $twig->print_to_file($partname);
        $twig->purge;
        $records = 0;
        $fileno += 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. As for the comment -- AFAIK any XML libraries are an extra item to install for perl, but there are several of them built in and included with the interpreter in Python. Has the first part of the prior sentence changed / become untrue in the years since I had any clue about perl?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Still true. The current perl philosophy with respect to the standard library is to try to keep it minimal(ish) instead of going full on batteries included.

Comment: You could use a python solution instead of perl, of course, but I don't like python unless someone pays me to write in it, so *I* didn't.

Comment: _nod_. I took money to maintain someone else's Perl early in my career, twenty-_mumble_ years ago; once was enough -- but I do understand having strong preferences. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- input file is nicely formatted as in the sample (eg, the entire contents of the file does not reside on a single line)
- the lines before the first `<stuRec>` (call these the 'header') and after the last `</stuRec>` (call these the 'tail') are to be written to each output file

One `awk` idea that writes *each* `stuRec` block to a *separate* file:

```
awk -v element="stuRec" '
BEGIN                          { find_hdr = 1; find_tail = 0 }
$0 ~ "<" element ">"           { find_hdr = find_tail = 0
                                 n++
                                 fname[n] = "output/part_" n ".xml"
                                 print hdr > fname[n]
                               }
find_hdr                       { hdr  = hdr  (hdr  == "" ? "" : ORS) $0; next }
find_tail                      { tail = tail (tail == "" ? "" : ORS) $0; next }
fname[n]                       { print $0 > fname[n] }
$0 ~ "</" element ">"          { close(fname[n]); find_tail = 1 }
END                            { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
                                     print tail >> fname[i]
                                     close(fname[i])
                                 }
                               }
' "student_records.xml"
```

This generates:

```
$ head -20 output/part*xml
==> output/part_1.xml <==
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stuRec>
 <as>
 <sourceSys>BBC</sourceSys>
 <acctDt>2023-04-04</acctDt>
 </as>
 <stats>
 <ss>
  <prov>AB</prov>
  <cono>1</cono>
 </ss>
 </stats>
</stuRec>
</studentData>

==> output/part_2.xml <==
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stuRec>
 <as>
 <sourceSys>RCD</sourceSys>
 <acctDt>2023-05-14</acctDt>
 </as>
 <stats>
 <ss>
  <prov>ON</prov>
  <cono>2</cono>
 </ss>
 </stats>
</stuRec>
</studentData>
```

**NOTES:**

- to place `X>1` number of `stuRec` blocks into a single file OP should be able to add an additional counter and use this to determine when to increment `n` (and thus create a new output file)
- if OP has problems getting an `X>1` solution working then I'd suggest asking a new question, making sure to provide the attempted code